# ListenableFuture: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type

Tags: android, android-room, guava

From the [documentation from Google](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries):

```
// Returns the number of users inserted.
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
public ListenableFuture<Integer> insertUsers(List<User> users);
```

This is my code:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
ListenableFuture<Integer> insert(List<VacationDay> vacationDay);
```

which yields this exception:

> error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.

Why? How to fix it?

**EDIT:**

These are my room related dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1'
implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:2.5.1"
```

Comment: Try Long or long instead of Integer

Comment: So the official documentation from Google is bogus to the point that it doesn't even compile?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MikeT's comment pointed out, Long instead of Integer works:

```
ListenableFuture<Long> insert(List<VacationDay> vacationDay);
```

That is, unlike the **`@Delete`** and **`@Update`** convenience annotations that return an **int**/**Integer** value, that indicates the number of affected rows (0 or greater).

**`@Insert`** returns a **long**/**Long** per inserted row *(Room will handle multiple inserts by returning an array of longs)*.

If a row was not inserted due to a captured conflict (e.g. a UNIQUE constraint conflict, that has been ignored by the `OnConflictStrategy`) then it will return -1 for the row that was not inserted.

- note that a Foreign Key conflict is not captured by the onConflictStrategy.
- see [OnConflictStrategy](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy) and The [ON CONFLICT clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)

The **reason for a long/Long** is that when inserting you are typically interested in each row which may or may not have been inserted. The value returned is the **rowid** of the inserted row (which may or may not be a known/coded/utilised column) and that it's value is a 64 bit signed integer value i.e. potentially too large to be handled by an int/Integer and hence why a long/Long is returned.

The **rowid** is a column that virtually all tables in Room have. If the Primary Key column is solely an integer type then it will be an alias of the **rowid** column and thus be the same value as the **rowid** column.

- see [Rowid Tables](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) for more information.

In regards to the comment *So the official documentation from Google is bogus to the point that it doesn't even compile?!*

Clearly the documentation is incorrect and is likely just a copy and paste and then amendment of the delete or update examples.

Answer (score 0):

In order to support `Guava` in `Room` you need to add extra dependency to your gradle

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"
```